# How to subscribe to multiple topics in FCM?

Tags: android, subscribe

I'm newly learning android studio, so however I have one doubt in developing a android app that:
How can we subscribe to multiple topics in FCM?

Here is my code

```
public void subscribeToPushService() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("News");

        Log.d("myname", "Subscribed");
        // Toast.makeText(Simple.this, "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Log and toast
        Log.d("myname", token);
        // Toast.makeText(Simple.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

you can see in the above code I have already subscribed to one topic "News" so

how can I subscribe to multiple topics instead of one?
Is it possible, if yes how can we do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Yes,find below sample code  for subscribe multiple topics**

```
public void subscribeToPushService() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("News");
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Movies");
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("etc");
}
```

**For unsubscribe topic**

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("Topic name");
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it in one request ? I know you can subscribe multiple people into a topic!

Comment: @Mat No. For mobile SDK this is the only way to do this.